# How to get notified when a custom directive has been initialized in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let us say I have a custom directive like this applied on a div:

```
<div my-custom-component></div>
```

In my controller, I want to define a function like this:

```
$scope.onAfterMyCustomComponentInit(){
         // Do something only once after the component is inited.
}
```

How do I get the above method in my controller called?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass you controller function to the directive from attribute & as soon as directive link function gets called you can fire the function which you have passed from the attribute. Before passing it from attribute you need to use `&` with scope variable name inside isolated scope of directive `scope: { callback: '&' }`

**Markup**

```
<div my-custom-component callback="myFunction()"></div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myCustomComponent', function(){
  return {
     scope: {
        callback: '&'
     },
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        //directive has initalized
        scope.callback(); //call controller method.
     }
  }

})
```

Comment: Thanks. But, does this mean, Angular has no built in notification mechanism that gets called when any directive is initialized?

Comment: @praveen_r no not as such.. Its not event driven.. You could define something like that using `$broadcast` & `$emit`.. and directive are also has good capability to accept `methods` & `variable`'s which can have either two way or one way binding enabled..